# SUM column and GROUP BY date MySQL (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This is an example of my database (huge database, one table).  I'm using MariaDB.

```
DATE        |   SIZE        |   FILES
2013-01-06  |   1600        |   30
2013-01-06  |   3200        |   14
2013-02-14  |   1600        |   3
2013-02-14  |   800         |   4
2013-05-19  |   6400        |   300
2013-05-19  |   9000000     |   15000
```

I am trying to sum the SIZE column and FILES columns by DATE.  For example, for 2013-01-06, the size would be 4800 and the FILES would be 44, and so on.  The query that I've tried is

```
SELECT DATE, SUM(SIZE) AS BYTES, SUM(FILES) AS FILES
FROM DB.DBSA
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '2013-01-06' AND '2013-05-19');
```

...but it only give the the grand total.

Comment: Try to add `GROUP BY DATE` at end of your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query engine recognizes this query as an aggregation query:

```
SELECT DATE, SUM(SIZE) AS BYTES, SUM(FILES) AS FILES
FROM DB.DBSA
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '2013-01-06' AND '2013-05-19');
```

However, there is no `group by` clause, so the aggregation is taken over all the data (subject to the filtering in the `where` clause, of course).

In most databases, this results in an error, something like "`Date` not recognized as a group variable".  MySQL chooses an arbitrary value of date (by default, you can set a parameter to have it generate an error as it would in standard SQL).

You need the group by:

```
SELECT DATE, SUM(SIZE) AS BYTES, SUM(FILES) AS FILES
FROM DB.DBSA
WHERE (DATE BETWEEN '2013-01-06' AND '2013-05-19')
group by date;
```

As another comment.  The column name `date` is a bad name because it conflicts with both a function name and a built-in data type.  Try to keep your names different from the built-in SQL names for things.

Comment: That worked!  Didn't realize it was something that simple!  =)