# How to sum columns and group by date column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

I have a model with following columns

### Charges Model

```
Date
fee
discount
```

### Data

```
1/1/15, 1, 1
1/1/15, 2, 1
2/2/15, 3, 3
```

I have a few named scopes like this_year

I want to do something like Charges.this_year.summed_up

How do I make a named scope for this.

### The returned response then should be:

```
1/1/15, 3, 2
2/2/15, 3, 3
```

Comment: no not really I am not looking for code, I have looked into grouping http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855821/group-by-sum-on-multiple-columns-in-rails-3
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800082/sum-column-and-group-by-date-mysql-mariadb

Most of the solutions are sql based, I am trying to look for a more basic approach that can be implemented in a straight forward manner.

You could recommend a gem or any link, I would accept a useful advice as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a model with a date field(eg. published_at) and 2 integer fields(eg. fee, discount). You can use "group" method to run GROUP BY on published_at. Then just use `sum` method if you want only sum of one fields. If you want more than one field, you have to run a select with SQL SUMs inside, to get multiple column sums. Here is an example.

```
Charge..group(published_at)
.select("published_at, SUM(fee) AS sum_fee, SUM(discount) AS sum_discount")
.order("published_at")
```

Note: Summarized fields won't show up in rails console return value prompt. But they are there for you to use.

Comment: i was working on similar lines, and the generated sql shows the summed up column when executed directly on the database, but i am unable to access it in any way. could you update your answer on how that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon what end result you want, you may want to look at `.group(:attribute)` rather than `.group_by`:

```
Charge.group(:date).each do |charge|
     charge.where('date = ?', charge.date).sum(:fee)
     charge.where('date = ?', charge.date).sum(:discount)
end
```

I found this approach easier, especially if setting multiple conditions on the data you want to extract from the table.

In any case, I had an accounting model that presented this kind of issue where I needed credit and debit plus type of payment info on a single table and spent a fruitful few hours learning all about `group_by` before realizing that `.group()` offered a simple solution.